# Python, reduce list of string doesn't work with newline?

Tags: python

I try to combine a list of string to string using reduce function but it doesn't work. I prefer to use reduce function anyway how do I fix this?

```
>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y + "\n", ["dog", "cat"])
# this doesn't work
# dogcat
>> "\n".join(["dog", "cat"])
# this works
# dog
# cat
```

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. You add a new line only at the end. You probably meant `x + '\n' + y`

Comment: @mousetail Hi! :)

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of join, is to put the element between each

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + "\n" + y, ["dog", "cat"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
###################### METHOD 1 ######################

strings = ["This", "is", "a", "list", "of", "strings"]

# join the strings using lambda
joined = lambda strings: "\n".join(strings)
print(joined(strings))

###################### METHOD 2 ######################

mylist = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

# use list comprehension to join the list of strings
mystring = "\n".join([str(x) for x in mylist])
print(mystring)

strings = ["This", "is", "a", "list", "of", "strings"]

###################### METHOD 3 ######################
import functools
list_of_strings = ["a", "b", "c"]
print(functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + "\n" + y, list_of_strings))
```

Comment: your second method is just like the first but you are unnecessarily adding `str(x)` even though the list already consists of strings.